# Set up switch with vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, switch-statement

I'm trying to learn C++, but I'm a little stuck.

I'm using [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany) and CentOS to create a basic gradebook application.

Geany is displaying red curly lines on the *for* and *cout* lines of the application. I feel like everything is in the correct syntax, but I get 'compilation failed.'

What is wrong with my source?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    // Declaration of local variables for gradebook
    vector<int> gradeVector;
    char choice;
    bool menu = true;

    // User Menu
    while (menu){
        cout << "This is the gradebook menu\n";
        cout << "Please enter (a) to Show All Grades\n";
        cout << "Please enter (l) to Show Last Grade\n";
        cout << "Please enter (g) to Add Grade\n";
        cout << "Please type 0 to Exit.\n";
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice){
            case 'a':
                for (i=0;i <= gradeVector.size(); i++)
                cout << "These are the grades entered: \n"<<gradeVector.at(i);
            break;
            case 'l':
                cout << "This was the last grade entered: \n" << gradeVector;
            break;
            case 'g':
                cout << "Please add a grade to the gradebook: \n" << cin >> gradeVector.push_back();
            break;
            case 0:
                menu = false;
            break;
            default:
                cout << "Please ONLY use lower-case a, l, g, or 0 as your choice.\n"
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your source doesn't consume the newline that follows your initial menu choice input. Whats wrong with your *question* would be missing info, namely describing what this is *supposed* to do, what it *seems* to do instead, and any suspicions you may be harboring as to why. Regarding compilation failure messages; **post them verbatim** after trying and failing to fix them. (start by declaring `i`, which should be obvious).

Comment: There are lots of errors in your code. One: in the for loop, `i` is not declared, use `int i`; second: `"This was the last grade entered: \n" << gradeVector;` makes no sense, use for example `gradeVector.at(gradeVector.size());` use a debugger first before posting the question

Comment: Right. I JUST noticed that my i is not declared. I just fixed that. The "This was the last graded entered: " line was just a guess. I forgot to mention that I needed guidance on that particular line. 

gradeVector.at(gradeVector.size()); should work let me try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple errors in you code. Firstly you forgot to declare integer `i`. You tried to output a vector, and from your text I gather you only want the last grade. Input should happen using a push_back, but it should be read into a temporary variable first. Correcting this and changing a bit of general code would make this your code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    // Declaration of local variables for gradebook
    vector<int> gradeVector;
    char choice;
    bool menu = true;

    // User Menu
    while (menu){
        cout << "This is the gradebook menu\n";
        cout << "Please enter (a) to Show All Grades\n";
        cout << "Please enter (l) to Show Last Grade\n";
        cout << "Please enter (g) to Add Grade\n";
        cout << "Please type 0 to Exit.\n";
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice){
            case 'a':
                cout << "These are the grades entered: \n"
                for (int i=0 ;i < gradeVector.size(); i++)
                    cout << gradeVector[i] << " ";
            break;
            case 'l':
                cout << "This was the last grade entered: \n" << gradeVector[gradeVector.size()-1];
            break;
            case 'g':
                cout << "Please add a grade to the gradebook: \n";
                int input;
                cin >> input;
                gradeVector.push_back(input);
            break;
            case 0:
                menu = false;
            break;
            default:
                cout << "Please ONLY use lower-case a, l, g, or 0 as your choice.\n";
        }

     }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I see where my errors are. Thank you. I modified the code to your example and the only problem I have now are with getting the last input in the Vector. I added this line but I'm getting an overflow error: **cout << "This was the last grade entered: \n" << gradeVector.at(gradeVector.size()-1);** parenthesis as opposed to brackets.

Answer (score 1):

For one, your *for* loop syntax is wrong.

```
for (i=0;i <= gradeVector.size(); i++)
```

That will give you a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) every time, it should be

```
for (i=0;i < gradeVector.size(); i++)
```

So you don't access out of range memory. Remember, the counting starts at 0, and you can't access more memory than you allocated.

Your compile error is here:

```
cout << "This was the last grade entered: \n" << gradeVector;
```

You can't cout a vector like that; you have to cout a specific element. If you want to cout all elements in a vector, use a *for* loop.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Hey man, quit necroing old post to the top with your worthless edits.